# Finding the coordinates at the minimum distance between a circle and a line in space?

Tags: geometry

[image]

[image]

Circle center o = (0.3501, -0.0881, -4.8466)

Normal vector of the circle n = (0.4163, -0.8326, -0.3653)

Radius of the circle r = 1.34954

Two points on the line:

Point a = (3.1932, -0.9005, 0.8082)

Point b = (1.9885, -0.9691, -0.8353)

Find a point p on the circle, such that the distance to the line ab is minimized.

As the circle and the line are not coplanar, the projection of the perpendicular from the foot of the perpendicular to the circle center onto the circle is no longer the shortest distance. As illustrated from a right perspective, the intersection of the circle on the plane perpendicular to the line ab, with the projection of the circle center onto this plane k, is the point where the shortest distance occurs.

Is my understanding correct? How to find the coordinates of point p?

Comment: https://www.geometrictools.com/Source/Distance3D.html